Setting up dynamic value in SCADA variables
I am working on a project in DIAView where I have three buttons that, when clicked, should dynamically assign values from specific variable groups (s11, s12, s13 for Group 1; s21, s22, s23 for Group 2; s31, s32, s33 for Group 3) to three indicators (named Diode1, Diode2, Diode3). However, I encountered syntax errors when using the Sub Button1_Click() structure, so I switched to a direct approach that compiled but still couldn't correctly assign values to the diodes. I am unsure whether to use .Value, .State, or another property to update the diodes and need a detailed solution on how to handle this in DIAView, including how to properly manage the button click events without the Sub syntax error.
any Solution to this ..
